# Java - Apostrophe error when reading words from text file into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am using the following method to read words in a .txt file into an array.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileArrayProvider {

public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}
}
```

The first word in my .txt file is "can't". However when I call this method and print the first word in the returned array, i get `can?t`. All the apostrophes in the words in the array are being replaced by `?`. How can I fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read your file in a specific character encoding. You cannot do this directly with `FileReader`.

Instead use a `FileInputStream` passed to an `InputStreamReader` which specifies a charset. In this case, we try with `UTF-8`.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");      
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();
System.out.println(lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]));
```

Comment: I am still getting a question mark instead of an apostrophe. Is there another charset I can try?

Comment: @user3044874 [There are tons you can try.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) I wouldn't try them one by one. Try to find which charset your character belongs to with google.