# How can I pull in words with apostrophes correctly? Words like "wouldn't" and "couldn't" are being placed into ArrayList as "wouldn" and "couldn"

Tags: java, regex, text-files, java.util.scanner, delimiter

IT Networking/programming student here trying to complete an assignment, and I've hit a snag. We're tasked with reading in a text file, placing the words into an ArrayList, and performing string operations on the content. I'm able to pull the words into the ArrayList, sort the content in ascending order, drop any words with less than four characters, remove duplicate entries, and remove numbers. What I'm finding though is that words with apostrophes are being "cut-off". Words like "wouldn't" and "couldn't" are being placed into my ArrayList as "wouldn" and "couldn".

I've tried different delimiters for my scanner object, but I can't seem to find the one that will keep apostrophes in words and not cut the word off after the apostrophe.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class textFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Scanner object reads in the required text file to the "words" ArrayList.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("textfile.txt"), "UTF-8");
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]");
            words.add(sc.next().toLowerCase());

        }
        // Closes the Scanner object used just above.
        sc.close();

        // Sorts the "words" ArrayList in ascending order.
        Collections.sort(words);

        // Creates the "wordsNoDuplicates" ArrayList. Removes duplicate strings.
        LinkedHashSet<String> wordsNoDup = new LinkedHashSet<String>(words);

        // Removes all words containing less than four characters.
        wordsNoDup.removeIf(u -> u.length() < 4);

        // Prints the total number of words in the "wordsNoDup" ArrayList
        System.out.println("Total Number of Words: " + wordsNoDup.size() + "\n");

        // Calculate and print the average word length.
        // double avgWordLength = 21186 / wordsNoDup.size();

        System.out.println("Average Word Length: " + 7.0 + "\n");

        // Print out the "words" ArrayList. Intended for debugging.
        System.out.print(wordsNoDup);

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Again, words like "couldn't", "shouldn't" and "wouldn't" are being pulled in as "couldn", "shouldn", and "wouldn". Seems like the apostrophe and anything after it are being dropped. I will openly admit I am not one who has an extensive understanding of Java or programming, but any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: As clearly stated its your "homework"... keep fidding around for a while and you get the hang of it. Hint.. in some cases python uses \\ if you need just one \.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Apostrophe error when reading words from text file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276489/java-apostrophe-error-when-reading-words-from-text-file-into-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usage of this in your code,

```
sc.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]");
```

Any character other than alphabets will act as delimiters and hence `'` will also act as delimiter, so I suggest changing your above line of code to this,

```
sc.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z']");
```

So `'` will no longer be treated as delimiter and should preserve `'` in the words.

But I think it should be better to read your text and use a proper regex to just match and filter your words so, you only exceptionally allow a `'` when it is present within a word and not may be outside a word.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Looks to be what I needed to do for this. I very much appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)